# TranferOwnership Recursion

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc, transfer

If i have a contract C that is the owner of contract B and contract B is owner of contract A. Can C in is contract call transferownership from contract A?
Please help

Comment: Show the contract's code. How ownership works is defined by the contract's code and it can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how Ownership is implemented in these contract. If using OpenZeppelin Ownable approach then this would not work. There, ownership is stored as a single address (which for contract A would be contract B's address) and then restricted functions check to ensure the caller's address is equal to the owner's address, otherwise revert. Thus, if contract C attempts to call contract A's transferOwnership function, contract A will check contract C's address (caller) against contract's B (owner), find a mismatch and revert transaction.

Comment: Hello sir! Very thanks for your good explanation! There is no form to change the owner of contract A with contract C?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you will need to change either how ownership is handled (make contract C also owner of contract A and allow for dual ownership) but a better approach is, as others have mentioned, to include a function in contract B that will call contract A's transfer ownership. So C calls B, B then call A as owner and transfers ownership.

Comment: Ok, but imagine that i cannot change contract B and A code, how can i call transferownership function from contract A on contract C?

Comment: Difficult to say without the contracts's source code but unless contract B has some internal logic to allow it to call contract A ownership transfer, it will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to B for calling C and transferownershipping. But be careful, you have to use `msg.sender` for checking the message owner instead of `tx.origin`

Comment: Im using OpenZeppelin Ownable approach, how can i do that on contract c?

Comment: You can add a function like this: ```function transferOwnershipFromC(address new) external onlyOwner { C.transferOwnership(address); }```

Comment: But the only person that can do that function is contract B! Imagine that i cannot change code from contract B and A, can i do that on contract C?

Comment: No! If you don't able to change codes of contract B, you can't do anything about it. Because you have to send an transaction to C from B, and the transaction should say transferownership. Contract addresses not like EOAs. If there is no function to do that, than there is no solution.